# Will run Ubuntu only over terminal increase my computer performace?

Tags: command-line, performance

I have this software that I need to run for a project I'm working on but it uses all my CPU and will take 10 days to finish. I want it to run faster so I can finish this earlier. My computer is already being used only for that but still not enough. I was planing to load Ubuntu only into bash shell so that the software will load faster since the computer doesn't have to load any GUI, my question is, will that really help or I won't get much more computing power using this?

Comment: You may be able to perform better if you have other systems with you. Try reading about PelicanHPC. Over 10 days you may be able to save about 2% of your clock speed daily given the average CPU usage on Ubuntu GNOME.

Comment: By the way it may help only if your application is CPU bound and is actually using all the CPU.

Comment: Short answer , yes, if you can avoid using gui, use command line

Comment: If you are processing a lot of data (from disk), or truly using CPU power (and not just iterative or hunting algorithms), then a review of the code (and re-design) may even halve the time needed. *Disabling the GUI will likely not ..*

Answer (score 5):

For most use cases it will not provide any noticeable improvement to run without the GUI. This is because most desktop computers are idle most of the time and the available system resources for running large jobs greatly exceed the amount you will use when you are at the computer. Even if you renice the process to a lower priority than all your interactive processes (e.g. `renice +10 <pid>`) the time savings will be minimal. That said, here are some cases where you might notice a difference:

- Your system has little memory relative to the processes you are running on it. This could cause active parts of your long running job to get paged to disk. If it is on disk then it can not be running on the CPU. A little bit of paging is not going to appreciably change the execution time of your long running job since the active part of the job will likely remain in memory but a lot of paging will slow everything down.
- You run processes in your GUI that use appreciable amounts of CPU and your background job is capable of having used those CPU resources. This is a complicated condition and typical desktop applications don't use significant amounts of CPU for extended periods of time. Most relevant here is that most modern CPUs are multi-core. If your job can't use 100% of all cores on your system then you have at least some cores always available for use by other processes.

Comment: Yeah in my case (on my old computer), I was running of memory in my X sessions. At least in the console I would have an extra 1Gb or 2Gb, which helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yeah. The GUI does consume resources that are most probably unnecessary in your case.